# finding all the mobius transformation.?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

find all the mobius  transformation that map the units disc$ D$  onto the   left half plane

$H^-$ = {$w \in C : Re w <0  $}

My attempts : I know that all the Möbius transformations can be written on the form

$$w=f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

here i don't know how can i find all the mobius transformation .

as im not getting in my heads  pliz help me

Comment: (1) Mobius transformations send (generalized) circles to (generalized) circles. ("Generalized" circles include straight lines in the plane.) (2) Mobius transformations act sharply 3-transitively - that is, they are determined by where they send any 3 points.

Comment: @anon,,,im not understanding,,ur 2) and 3) ..lines

Comment: I only had (1) and (2), not (3). Do you mean you (a) don't understand what I'm saying or (b) don't understand how to apply what I'm saying to your problem?

Comment: (2) Mobius transformations act sharply 3-transitively - that is, they are determined by where they send any 3 points......this line not getting in my head

Comment: If you know $(u,v,w)$ and $(f(u),f(v),f(w))$, then $f$ is uniquely determined. (You can't have two different Mobius transformations that send $(u,v,w)$ to the same tuple.) So I'll add a part (3): the cross ratio $$f(z)=\frac{z-u}{z-v}\frac{w-v}{w-u} $$ is a Mobius transformation that maps the ordered triple $(u,v,w)$ to $(0,\infty,1)$. Note $0,\infty,1$ are all on the real axis. Thus, this maps the unit disk to either the upper or lower half-planes (since it maps the unit circle to the real axis). Can you go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It's a standard result that the Möbius transformations which map the unit disk onto itself are those of the form$$z\mapsto\omega\frac{z-a}{1-\overline az},$$with $|\omega|=1$ (there's a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1941331/446262)). Now, find *one* Möbius which maps the left half plane onto the unit disk and you're don (well, almost).

Comment: if i take a = -1 which -1<0  then  $f(z) = \frac { z-1} {1-z}$  is the required  mobius transformation....Is  its corrects ??? @ jose carlos sir

Comment: @lomber No. That's the constant function $-1$.

Comment: @ Jose carlos sir,,,i was thinking   but  .. im not getting  that .... mobius which maps the left half plane onto the unit disk

Comment: @lomber Take$$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1}.$$

Comment: carlos sir..but according to ur given answer in above  that is $f(z) = \frac {z-a}{1-az} $ that mean if i put a= -1  as  im getting $ f(z) = \frac{z+1} {1+z}$.....but  u have wriiten  $f(z) = \frac {z+1}{z-1}$

Comment: @lomber The functions that I mentioned in my answer are the Möbius transformations which map the open unito disk onto itself.

Comment: carlos sir ..one last doubts .... how  u  take $ f(z) = \frac {z+1}{z-1}$???  is there  any procedure  and how can u  claim that$ f(z) = \frac {z+1}{z-1}$ maps the left half plane onto the unit disk ?

Comment: @lomber Sure. The elements of the left half plane are those numbers $z$ which are closer to $-1$ than to $1$. In other words, $|z+1|<|z-1|$. But this means that $\left|\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right|<1$.

Comment: ok,,,,thanks  a lots @jose carlos sir ...now  i got its